# Do I need a Promise to handle the response

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, response

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. If possible, could someone please point me in the right direction?

I believe I may need to use a promise and wait until all the data has been pushed to the array but not quite sure if there's a better way of handling this?

```
router.get('/notifications/:user_id', (req, res) => {

    console.log('get comments by ID route received a GET request');

    var user_id = req.params.user_id;
console.log(user_id)
    
//get all posts belonging to a user
var getNotificationsById = 'SELECT user_profiles.forename, user_profiles.surname, user_profiles.profile_image, user_posts.id, user_posts.title, user_posts.price, count(distinct post_comments.id) AS total_comments, sum(post_likes.likes=1) AS total_likes FROM user_posts LEFT JOIN post_comments ON user_posts.id = post_comments.post_id LEFT JOIN post_likes ON user_posts.id = post_likes.post_id LEFT JOIN post_comment_likes ON user_posts.id = post_comment_likes.post_id LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON post_likes.user_id = user_profiles.id WHERE user_posts.user_id = ? GROUP BY user_posts.id ORDER BY user_posts.created DESC'

//get all items belonging posts using post_id for a user
//  var getRelationsById = 'SELECT user_profiles.forename, user_profiles.surname, user_profiles.profile_image, user_posts.id, user_posts.title, user_posts.price, count(distinct post_comments.id) AS total_comments, sum(post_likes.likes=1) AS total_likes FROM user_posts LEFT JOIN post_comments ON user_posts.id = post_comments.post_id LEFT JOIN post_likes ON user_posts.id = post_likes.post_id LEFT JOIN post_comment_likes ON user_posts.id = post_comment_likes.post_id LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON post_likes.user_id = user_profiles.id WHERE post_comment_likes.post_id = ? GROUP BY user_posts.id ORDER BY user_posts.created DESC'
var getRelationsById = 'SELECT user_profiles.forename, user_profiles.surname, user_profiles.profile_image, user_posts.id, user_posts.title, user_posts.price, count(distinct post_comments.id) AS total_comments, sum(post_likes.likes=1) AS total_likes FROM user_posts LEFT JOIN post_comments ON user_posts.id = post_comments.post_id LEFT JOIN post_likes ON user_posts.id = post_likes.post_id LEFT JOIN post_comment_likes ON user_posts.id = post_comment_likes.post_id LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON post_likes.user_id = user_profiles.id WHERE post_comment_likes.post_id = ? GROUP BY post_comments.id ORDER BY user_posts.created DESC'
var userPostId = [];
var userResult = [];


var query = connection.query(getNotificationsById, [user_id], (error, result) => {
if(error) {
    console.error(error);
    logging.error.error(error);
    return;
}
var count = 0
//co(function*(){
for(i in result) {
    count++
    console.log('count total = ' + count + ' or more')
    var post_id = result[i].id
    userPostId.push(post_id)

    var query = connection.query(getRelationsById, [post_id], (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
            logging.error.error(error);
            return;
        }
        var count = 0
        for(i in result) {
            count++
            console.log('data found = ' + count)
            userResult.push(result)
        }
        //const message = "Successful"
        //res.status(200).json({message: message, status: 200, result: result})
        console.log(result)
    })
}
const message = "Successful"
res.status(200).json({message: message, status: 200, result: userResult})
});
```

});

Comment: Lots of things you need to clean up before attacking the main problem.  For starters, don't ever use `for/in` for iterating an array.  Use `for/of` in modern Javascript.  Then, manually declare ALL your variables using `let` or `const` (no more use of `var`).  You have undeclared `i` variables that will become implicit globals and they are nested inside loops so will conflict with one another.

Comment: You do not strictly *need* promises, but they will definitely simplify waiting for the asynchronous database results.

Comment: You probably should rewrite the SQL so that you will need to make only a single (or at most two) database queries, not a large number of them